# How to display the number of people who like posts

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a code that displays posts added by a user. The post consists of the name, the added time, the content of the post and 4 buttons. The problem is that I want to display the number of people who like this post next to each button. I know I have to create a new function for this, but I don't know how to display it, because posts are displayed using a foreach loop, so if I were to create a new function I would have to give foreach to display, but then it probably wouldn't work. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do it?

```js
 <?php foreach ($tweet->userData as $user) { ?>
            <div class='col-xl-8'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='btn-block d-flex justify-content-between'>
                        <div>
                           <?php  echo $user['autor']   ?>
                            </div>
                        <div>
                           <?php echo $user['date_to_add'] ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php echo $user['comment'] ?>
                <form action='' method='post'>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-12 col-xl-12 d-flex justify-content-between'>
                            <button class='button2' name='dodaj_like'><i class='fas fa-heart'></i><input type='hidden' name='like' value="<?php echo $user['id']?>" />Cool</button>
                            <button class='button2' name='dodaj_dislike'><i class='fas fa-heart-broken'></i><input type='hidden' name='dislike' value="<?php echo $user['id']?>"/>Awful</button>
                            <button class='button2' name='dodaj_comment' ><i class='far fa-comment-dots'></i><input type='hidden' name='comment' value="<?php echo $user['id']?>"/>Comment</button>
                            <button class='button2' name='dodaj_share'><i class='far fa-share-square'></i><input type='hidden' name='share' value="<?php echo $user['id']?>"/>Share</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

```js
public function display()
    {
        $field5 = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT post.id, CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS autor, comment, date_to_add FROM user JOIN post ON user.id = post.user_id where user_id = :user_id group by post.id DESC");
        $sql->bindParam(':user_id',$field5, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sql->execute();

            if($sql->rowCount())
            {
                $this->userData = [];

                while ($row = $sql->fetch())
                {
                    $this->userData[] = $row;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can't you join with the likes in the query in `display()`?

Comment: Or just call the function inside the `foreach` loop: `$likes = get_like_count($user['id']);`

Comment: Then just display `$likes` in the HTML.

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` in the query in `display`? Nothing is being aggregated.

Comment: SELECT count('post_id') as amount FROM post_like where post_id =:post_id This is my query, which return count likes. The problem is WHERE clauses, which are different. But you know how I Can join this query ?

Answer (score 0):

Join with the `post_like` table in the query in `display`.

```
$sql = $this->database->connect()->prepare("
    SELECT post.id, CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS autor, comment, date_to_add,
            COUNT(*) AS likes 
    FROM user 
    JOIN post ON user.id = post.user_id 
    JOIN post_like ON post.id = post_like.post_id
    where user_id = :user_id 
    group by post.id 
    ORDER BY post.id DESC");
```

Then you can use `$user['likes']` in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: `$sql = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT post.id, CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS autor, comment, date_to_add, count(post_like.post_id) as likes FROM user JOIN post ON user.id = post.user_id JOIN post_like ON post.id = post_like.post_id where post.user_id = :user_id order by post.id DESC");`  This query show only first post. In my opinion is any error in WHERE clause.

Comment: You're missing `GROUP BY post.id`